# How to return the name of the instance of a class in Java

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java (and programming), and there should be a simple answer to this, but I could not find it. I want to write a code that would print the value of the reference name of an instance variable. For example:

```
Public class Person {
    Person() {
        //attributes, height, weight, etc.
    }

    Person Person1 = new Person();
}
```

I would like to write a line of code that would produce something to the tune of

"The *attribute* of Person1 is..."

Something to the tune of System.out.println("The *attribute* of Person1 " +(*????*)+" is ....")

I was unable to find or create a method that would return the name Person1.

Comment: Are you talking about getters and setters??

Comment: I think OP wants to print out the the *variable name* `Person1`.

Comment: @sstan, that is correct.

Comment: If only you were coding in C# 6, then you would be able to do `nameof(Person1)`. Sorry, couldn't resist. :)

Comment: I Think you should use Java Reflection which enables you to get the names of all public members of a class such as Fields, Methods and Constructors etc. :-) 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not generally possible to do exactly what you want.  I don't think variable names are even compiled into the classes.

It can be done with compile time annotations but it's not trivial.

Comment: Then it's probably easier to make an arguments constructor with a string argument "name" and print that. But thanks, I suspected that it wasn't simple, because I was unable to find a straightforward answer anywhere.

Comment: You are correct, it is much easier.  Just so you know--compile time annotations give you access to the code before the variable names are compiled away so it's possible and what you are asking might be useful in some kind of logging scenario, but it's best just to "Name" the object.  There is a tutorial about the compile-time annotations here if you were curious: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17876.html

Answer (score 3):

"Person1" is not the name of the instance, but instead is the name of a variable that holds the reference to the instance.  The instance itself has no name.  You will have to give it an attribute of name if you care to keep it.

```
public class Person {
   private final String name;
   public Person(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return this.name;
   }
}
```

then you can do:

```
Person person1 = new Person("Jeff");

System.out.println("Person1's name is: " + person1.getName());
```

The output of that will be:

> Person1's name is: Jeff

Comment: I get it, but in that case I would have to use an arguments constructor and repeat the name when I create the instance on the person.

Comment: The variable name isn't stored anywhere. It needn't even be stored in the byte code.   Think of it as a holder, not the object.  "__My left hand__ holds a __cup__.  What is the name of the __cup__?"

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do that you should override the toString() function 
Something like this

```
/* Returns the string representation of your class object .*/
     @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "The attributes of this person are :height - " + height + " weight - " + weight  + // you are print out all your properties. 
        }
```

Now whenver you want to print the object you can do

```
System.out.println(person1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how familiar you are with programming languages in general.  I see you say you are new to Java, so I'll start there.  Java, like many object-oriented languages, uses inheritance when you create classes.  In Java, when you define a class you can use the "extends" keyword to sub-class and use or override any methods in the parent class.  Now, in Java, **ALL** classes automatically inherit from this class called Object.

This is very useful to know, because Object contains a few useful methods, most notably of them is "toString()".  You do not need to use extends to get these methods btw.  Now, toString on its own is not useful, but you can override it to print out what you want.

```
public class Person
{
    String name;
    int age;

    Person(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name is: " + name + "and age is: " + age";
    }
}
```

Notice the toString() method I defined there?  Anytime you call this method on an object, you will get that string printed out.  So for instance, in your example:

```
Person person1 = new Person("Ford Prefect", 42);

System.out.println(person1.toString()); //Will print what we defined in toString.
```

You don't even need the .toString(), just person1 because the JVM will realize you meant to use toString.  If you use IntelliJ IDE, you can do Alt + Insert and select toString() to override it.  IDEs are wonderful tools to help you be more efficient.  Good luck!

Comment: Turns out, not very. But I understand what you are saying; I was just wondering if the name of the variable "Person1" is stored anywhere so it can be accessed at runtime; it appears not.

Comment: The compiler actually removes a lot of information since the JVM (What runs the compiled Java bytecode) doesn't really need it.  Person1 is there as a reference to help you refer to it in your code, but means nothing at run-time.  Person1 is essentially a reference to a memory address that stores that particular Person object you created (The call to new returns it).   In fact, if you remove your own .toString() and call the Object one, it will print the memory address the object is at.

Comment: I know, because I tried printing with a "this" and I got something like Person @13gh45